# How to plot multiple ROC curves in one plot with legend and AUC scores in python?

Tags: python, plot, roc, auc

I am building 2 models.

Model 1

```
modelgb = GradientBoostingClassifier()
modelgb.fit(x_train,y_train)
predsgb = modelgb.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1]
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,predsgb, average='macro', sample_weight=None)
```

Model 2

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(x_train,y_train)
predslog = model.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1]
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,predslog, average='macro', sample_weight=None)
```

How do i plot both the ROC curves in one plot , with a legend & text of AUC scores for each model ?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: i have matplotlib , however whatever you can suggest - i can import the relevant library

Comment: I was asking for the model...

Comment: sklearn.ensemble for GBM and sklearn.linear_model for Logistic

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adapting this to your data:

```
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(0).clf()

pred = np.random.rand(1000)
label = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
fpr, tpr, thresh = metrics.roc_curve(label, pred)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(label, pred)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="data 1, auc="+str(auc))

pred = np.random.rand(1000)
label = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
fpr, tpr, thresh = metrics.roc_curve(label, pred)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(label, pred)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="data 2, auc="+str(auc))

plt.legend(loc=0)
```

Comment: I think roc_curve is supposed to be ran with predicted probabilities, not predicted labels: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Answer (score 12):

Just by adding the models to the list will plot multiple ROC curves in one plot. Hopefully this works for you!

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

# Add the models to the list that you want to view on the ROC plot
models = [
{
    'label': 'Logistic Regression',
    'model': LogisticRegression(),
},
{
    'label': 'Gradient Boosting',
    'model': GradientBoostingClassifier(),
}
]

# Below for loop iterates through your models list
for m in models:
    model = m['model'] # select the model
    model.fit(x_train, y_train) # train the model
    y_pred=model.predict(x_test) # predict the test data
# Compute False postive rate, and True positive rate
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, model.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1])
# Calculate Area under the curve to display on the plot
    auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,model.predict(x_test))
# Now, plot the computed values
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s ROC (area = %0.2f)' % (m['label'], auc))
# Custom settings for the plot 
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('1-Specificity(False Positive Rate)')
plt.ylabel('Sensitivity(True Positive Rate)')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()   # Display
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question. It will help more people that way.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this ...

```
#ROC Curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
y_pred_prob1 = classifier1.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr1 , tpr1, thresholds1 = roc_curve(Y_test, y_pred_prob1)

y_pred_prob2 = classifier2.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr2 , tpr2, thresholds2 = roc_curve(Y_test, y_pred_prob2)


y_pred_prob3 = classifier3.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr3 , tpr3, thresholds3 = roc_curve(Y_test, y_pred_prob3)

y_pred_prob4 = classifier4.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr4 , tpr4, thresholds4 = roc_curve(Y_test, y_pred_prob4)


plt.plot([0,1],[0,1], 'k--')
plt.plot(fpr1, tpr1, label= "Linear")
plt.plot(fpr2, tpr2, label= "Poly")
plt.plot(fpr3, tpr3, label= "RBF")
plt.plot(fpr4, tpr4, label= "Sigmoid")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("FPR")
plt.ylabel("TPR")
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve


fig = plot_roc_curve( clf, x_train_bow, y_train)
fig = plot_roc_curve( clf, x_test_bow, y_test, ax = fig.ax_)
fig.figure_.suptitle("ROC curve comparison")
plt.show()
```

Basically `plot_roc_curve` function plot the roc_curve for the classifier. So if we use `plot_roc_curve` two times without the specifying `ax` parameter it will plot two graphs. So here we store the first gragh in the figure variable  and access its axis and provide to the next `plot_roc_curve` function, so that the plot appear of the axes of the first graph only.

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem too. Can you help me to understand why you used '_' (underscore) in ax = fig.ax_

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve

classifiers = [log_reg, decision_tree, decision_forest]
ax = plt.gca()
for i in classifiers:
    plot_roc_curve(i, X_test, y_test, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Why (or when) might I want to use this approach instead the accepted answer? Are there benefits to this variation? If so, could you update your response to include details?